# Pythons SQLAlchemy does not recognize Primary key column and complains, why?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, primary-key

I have this MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `affiliations` (
  `affiliation_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(333) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`affiliation_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

and this Model:

```
class Affiliation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'affiliations'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload : True'}

    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Affiliation({name!r}'.format(name=self.name)
```

When I initiate

```
session = database.get_session(engine)
aff = session.query(Affiliation).first()
print repr(aff)
```

SQLAlchemy returns this Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Affiliation|affiliations could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'affiliations'
```

I have rewritten the model an the database several times, doublechecked every name, altered columns, but I can't find why SQLAlchemy complains. **As you can see in the `CREATE STATEMENT` of the table, there is a Primary Key defined. Why can't SQLAlchemy find it?**

I have defined other tables equivalently and the code works great.

Comment: Ss this a typo `__table_args__ = {'autoload : True'}`, whereas it should have been `__table_args__ = {'autoload' : True}`?

Comment: @van This code is only a copypaste. So this could be the reason, why it did not work. Thanks for pointing out!